# Access a Windows 7 shared folder while using a public network profile

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I have two computers, let's call them A and B. I am sharing a folder on computer B and while the windows firewall is disabled, I can access it without any problems. However, when I enable the windows firewall on computer B I can't access the shared folder anymore. I am using the public network profile on computer B, however I enabled "File and Printer sharing" in the network center. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, also I have problems on "debugging", the windows firewall seems not to be very verbose.

In case this maybe makes a difference, both computers are on different networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution:
Go to the advanced settings of the windows firewall, choose incoming rules, then look for the rule "File and printer sharing (SMB incoming)" (or similar to that, I am not running an english windows version). Double click it and go to "area" (I guess this will be really translated different, just look for the a tab where you can set local and remote ip addresses for the rule). You will note, that the remote ip address is limited to the local subnet - change it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added an exception for file and printer sharing on both types of networks in the firewall?

Go to the control panel, click on System and Security, then on "Allow a program through Windows Firewall". Click "Change Settings", then scroll down to "File and Printer Sharing" and make sure it is checked for both Home/Work and Public networks. Click OK, and see if the file sharing now works.

[image: windows firewall exceptions]